# splitting input words into an array

Tags: php, regex

I have little experience with PHP and regular expressions. I created a simple html input form and a submit button. i would like to do the following:

When the button is clicked, regexp splits the input string into an array of words:

1. that are all lowercase (with all ã changed to a)
2. and are all 10 symbols long.

Should it be like that?

```
$search_string = $_GET['keywords'];

$regexp = preg_split(^[a-zA-Z]{1,10}+$, $search_string);

$regexp = strtolower($search_string);
```

This is my simple html code:

```
<div>
       <label for="keywords">keywords:</label>
       <input type="text" name="keywords">
</div> 
<input type="submit" value="Add Records">
```

Can you help me improve my regexp code? It doesn't seem to be working.

This is my code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="htmlform.php" method="POST">
        keywords <input type="text" name="keywords">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <?php 

        $search_string = $_GET['keywords'];

        $regexp = preg_split("/^[a-zA-Z]{1,10}+$/", $search_string);

         $regexp = strtolower($search_string);

     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You say the code isn't working.  What's the output that you've gotten when you try running your code?

Comment: when i combine html and php nothing is output

Comment: Enable error reporting. Regexp into quotes and delimiters.

Comment: At least the regexp isn't properly quoted, try `$regexp = preg_split('/^[a-zA-Z]{1,10}+$/', $search_string);`

Comment: Using a + after a {} is invalid Regex as they are both quantifiers.

Comment: You probably arent printing out any values and also might not have a form element wrapped around your inputs.  Can you post up your full file that you have?

Comment: Did i do it right? $regexp = preg_split("/^[a-zA-Z]{1,10}+$/", $search_string); and how do i echo it:  echo $regexp?

Comment: @BenMansley: Using a + after a {} is a perfectly valid quantifier that is called a possessive quantifier. It is useless here, but it's valid.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is because your form method is POST but you are looking at $_GET?

```
$search_string = $_POST['keywords'];
```